# while opening the page getting error there is no row at position 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

I am trying to open feedback form but showing below error
 "There is no row at position 0."
I have already checked database, there is a row for this query "select zzfname from sap_empmst where pernr = "

Here is my code...

```
public partial class feedback : System.Web.UI.Page
{
DataAccess Getdata=new DataAccess();
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=cluster;User ID=ocgpis;Password=pisocg;unicode=true");
OracleConnection con1 = new OracleConnection("Data Source=oragc;User ID=ipcltos;Password=ipcltos;unicode=true");
//OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.127.240.231/ocgpis;User ID=ocgpis;Password=pisocg;unicode=true");
//OracleConnection con1 = new OracleConnection("Data Source=10.127.240.216/ipcldb;User ID=ipcltos;Password=ipcltos;unicode=true");
OracleConnection con2 = new OracleConnection("Data Source=cluster;User ID=RGSS;Password=RGSS;unicode=true");
string strMessage = ""; int mins_now = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1_pl.Text = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    string sqlstr = "select zzfname from sap_empmst where pernr = '" +  Label1_pl.Text + "'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlstr, con1);
    adp.Fill(ds);
    string zzfname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();
    Label2_name.Text = zzfname;
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance

Comment: Have you debugged the code? Are you getting the value of  userId from session?

Comment: Can you place a breakpoint at adp.fill(ds) and see what is the content of sqlstr. Then try executing the same query in SQL

Comment: @RahulSingh yes there is one login page first from this page userid redirect to feedback page.

Comment: @Thangadurai i have already executed same query in sqldevloper and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Error Says that Your are accessing a row which is Not present so,

Always Check For whether Row exists in `DataSet/DataTable` using `RowCount`

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    Label1_pl.Text = Session["UserID"].ToString();
    string sqlstr = "select zzfname from sap_empmst where pernr = '" +  
    Label1_pl.Text + "'";
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(sqlstr, con1);
    adp.Fill(ds);

    if(ds!=null)
    if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
    string zzfname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["zzfname"].ToString();
    Label2_name.Text = zzfname;
}


}

}
```

Comment: getting below error now
Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected

Source Error:

 

Line 38:   {
Line 39:        
Line 40:    string zzfname = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].["zzfname"].ToString();
Line 41:           Label2_name.Text = zzfname;
Line 42:   }

Comment: did you use breakpoints ? i think error is due to some other reasons.Error is not specific